# $u,v$ are harmonic conjugate with each other in some domain

Tags: complex-analysis

$u,v$ are harmonic conjugate with each other in some domain , then we need to show

$u,v$ must be constant.

as $v$ is harmonic conjugate of $u$ so $f=u+iv$ is analytic.

as $u$ is harmonic conjugate of $v$ so $g=v+iu$ is analytic.

$f-ig=2u$ and $f+ig=2iv$ are analytic, but from here how to conclude that $u,v$ are constant? well I know they are real valued function, so by open mapping theorem they are constant?

Comment: Yes. You are completely correct.

Comment: @Wow sir, how you say by open mapping theorem they are constant? I used different method to say they are constant: let say $h= 2u$ and $h$ is analytic, so $h$ is analytic function whose imaginary part is constant hence $h$ is constant. So $u$ is constant. Similarly, say $k=2iv$ which is analytic and hence $k$ is analytic function whose real part is constant and hence $k$ is constant. So $v$ is constant. **Is this method is fine?** and after concluding that $u$ and $v$ are constant , **can we say $f$ is constant ?** sir Please reply.

Comment: You are alos correct Akash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. I add some remarks:

1. $v$ is a conjugate of $u$ if and only if $-u$ is a conjugate of $v$ (since $u+iv$  and $v-iu$ are constant multiples of each other)
2. Since the harmonic conjugate is unique up to additive constant, the assumption that $u$ is a conjugate of $v$ implies (because of 1) that $u=-u+\text{const}$, and conclusion follows.
3. Related to 1: the [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) $H$ satisfies $H\circ H=-\text{id}$.